# Conditional prepared statement not switching

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have the following PHP code, which is meant to insert data in the event that the username field is empty for a given username, or update data if a username exists. At the moment, the insert was previously working fine, but it would never switch to the update clause.

Now however, the insert clause fails to recognise my test variable, for no apparent reason. The errors I get are:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

and

```
Notice: Undefined variable: checkUsername
```

which are quite recent.

```
if($cmd=="submitinfo"){

$usernameQuery = "select username from USERS where username = $username";

$xblah = $con->query($usernameQuery);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($xblah))
  {
    $checkUsername = $row['username'];

  }

if ($checkUsername == null) {

$userQuery = "INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($userInfo = $con->prepare($userQuery)) {
    $userInfo->bind_param("ssssssssssssssssssss", $username, $firstname, $lastname, $flaggedauctions, $lastauction, $street1, $city1, $postcode1, $street2, $city2, $postcode2, $phone, $mobilephone, $fax, $email, $website, $bank, $banknumber, $accountnumber, $comments);
    $userInfo->execute();
    $userInfo->close();
    echo "true";
} else {
echo "false";
}
print_r($con->error);
}

else if ($checkUsername == $username) {

$userQuery = "UPDATE USERS SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?, flaggedauctions = ?, lastauction = ?, street1 = ?, city1 = ?, postcode1 = ?, street2 = ?, city2 = ?, postcode2 = ?, phone = ?, mobilephone = ?, fax = ?, email = ?, website = ?, bank = ?, banknumber = ?, accoutnumber = ? WHERE username = ?";
if ($userInfo = $con->prepare($userQuery)) {
    $userInfo->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $flaggedauctions, $lastauction, $street1, $city1, $postcode1, $street2, $city2, $postcode2, $phone, $mobilephone, $fax, $email, $website, $bank, $banknumber, $accountnumber, $username);
    $userInfo->execute();
    $userInfo->close();
    echo "true";
} else {
echo "false";
}
print_r($con->error);
}
}
```

What is a preferred way to do an update or an insert depending on the content of $username matched against the username field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

That's your error message? I think your problem is this line:

```
$xblah = $con->query($usernameQuery);
```

Do a `var_dump` on $xblah. I suspect your query is failing. Probably because you haven't fetched `$username` from your input. And for love of root, be sure to escape it! `mysql_real_escape_string()` will do what you want.

Comment: Yep. The other query is parameterised, why not this one?

Comment: $xblah prints out bool(false) ?

Comment: @Josh That means your query is failing. Make sure you actually have input in $username.

Comment: @Kalium var_dump $username prints out a string of 15 chracters, the correct username. I am getting username from GET, and the input is definitly there.

Comment: @Josh Then escape the username correctly, and try running the query manually. Your query may be malformed.

Comment: Escaping makes no difference, and the query works perfectly manually.

Comment: Check what you get from $con->error() after the query fails. That should give you something more specific.

Comment: Hmm, how odd. It gives: Unknown column 'usernamestring' in 'where clause'

Comment: it seems to be trying to use $username in place of username..., except when I print out the query I get: elect username from USERS where username = usernamestring, which is correct.

Comment: Try this: $usernameQuery = "select username from USERS where username = '" . $con->escape_string($username) . "'";

Comment: Basically, you're doing a string comparison. You *MUST* quote the string that is input.

Comment: Yes...it works perfectly now...it must have been something really odd in that username, as $userquery was fine before...

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember to always always *ALWAYS* quote your strings and escape your input.

Comment: Now my only concern is that I want to use my update query, without overwriting existing fields unless there is new input.which will probably need a seperate question.

Comment: Many many thanks, I have to go through and make sure everything is escaped/parameterised etc..

Comment: I think you're OK. The method you're using is tolerable, and probably about as good as it's going to get without a full abstraction layer involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL and the username is unique, you can use this handy SQL:

```
INSERT INTO users (?, ?, ...) ON
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=?,
lastname=?, ...)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for full documentation.

Comment: So I should use this in place of the conditional code I currently have?